# Binding SelectedIndex to a different Collection then the Collection of the itemsSource

Tags: c#, listview, combobox, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

Hi I am developing an application for WinRT with MVVM-light. What i am trying to do is fill a combobox with items, for example 4 kinds of fruit. And my SelectedItem should be the first kind of fruit to which the combobox is bound. This works but, the next step is that i want to make the selectedIndex change. For example when The first kind of fruit is sold out then the SelectedIndex should automattically change to the second item in the Collection Of my Combobox.

So if you would want to buy 10 pieces of fruit you would get 10 comboboxes on your screen in which you can select the kind of fruit, when you have selected an apple in 4 of them and there are no apples anymore then the selectedindex of the other comboboxes should change to the second kind of fruit.

I know it is a bit of a confusing question.

**Basically** what i need is to be able to bind my Selectedindex to a property in a Collection that is different from the Collection of my combobox. I will give you a bit of xaml that will hopefully explain a bit more:

```
 </ListView>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel IsHitTestVisible="{Binding HitTest}"  Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:dd MMM yyyy}' }"></TextBlock>
               <ComboBox Width="196"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FruitKind.FruitList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=FruitKind.FruitComboBoxItem, Source={StaticResource Locator}, ElementName={Binding Path=FruitIndex}}">
                  <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FruitKind}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
                  </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
              </ComboBox>
          </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I'm not sure if this is possible by the way.
thnx

Comment: how are the combo boxes generated?  You can bind the selected item to any property in your viewmodel and change that value from within any function

Comment: The comboboxes are bound to an observablecollection that, when i use selected item the combobox just stays blank when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind to the selected item instead of index.  THis allows you to work with a object/property of the viewmodel that you can modify any way you want:

ie:

```
<ComboBox Width="196"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FruitKind.FruitList, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=FruitKind.FruitObject, Source={StaticResource Locator}, ElementName={Binding Path=FruitIndex}}">
```